# Restrict ActiveRecord ID query to only use real integers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Right now I'm finding ActiveRecord's query to be too flexible. Namely:

```
MaintenanceOrder.where(id:" 1   ")
=> [#<MaintenanceOrder id: 1...] 
MaintenanceOrder.where(id:"1.2")
=> [#<MaintenanceOrder id: 1...] 
MaintenanceOrder.where(id:"1/2")
=> [#<MaintenanceOrder id: 1...] 
MaintenanceOrder.where(id:"x")
=> []
MaintenanceOrder.where(id:"? ")
=> []
```

I would like a record to b found ONLY if what's passed to the `id` is a string consisting of nothing other than integers and spaces (with any leading 0s removed). Obviously I could use regex to figure this out in advance of the query, but I'm wondering if there's some Rails way to do this automagically. That way, I will be able to do something like:

```
object = MaintenanceOrder.where(id: some_id)
if object.exists?
  ...
```

Instead of doing something like this

```
if some_id is invalid
  ...
else MaintenanceOrder.where(id:some_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
[1] pry(main)> User.where('id like ?', "   22878 ")
  User Load (65.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (id like '   22878 ')
=> []

VS.

[2] pry(main)> User.where('id like ?', 22878)
  User Load (69.9ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (id like 22878)
=> [#<User:0x0000000ad69070
  id: 22878,
  ....
```

And you will have to check for `any?` rather than `present?` or apply `first` on your `where` results.

Comment: Tried it with id `1` got error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "id": syntax error: SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders"  WHERE (BINARY id = '1')`

Comment: @james: Well, you do not expect to use SQLite on production, are you? I tried it on MySql.

Comment: @james: For Sqlite you can try this `User.where('id like ?', "   22878 ")`. It works for MySql, and it should work for Sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

instead of where you can use the find method. From the docs: " If the primary key is an integer, find by id coerces its arguments using to_i"

```
Person.find(1)          # returns the object for ID = 1
Person.find("1")        # returns the object for ID = 1
Person.find("31-sarah") # returns the object for ID = 31
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find

Comment: I should have been more specific, in the 3rd example in your answer, I would like an object to NOT be found

Comment: @james gotcha, im no expert with rails but im not sure if there is a way to do this automatically. I would just create a custom find method in the model.rb file and use that from your controller/services instead